# services-code-scanner doesnt work suddenly

Tags: java, android

I have installed implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-code-scanner:16.1.0' as specify this documentation https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner. At first it work perfect but suddenly it stoped to work anymore. The problem is in execution time. Instead to open the camera to scan the barcode it raise a failure than I can catch with addOnFailureListener. In the Logcat I can see this error:

1512-5684  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{6dee8ad u0 com.xxxxx.yyyyy/com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.internal.GmsBarcodeScanningDelegateActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=4 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6535 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6516 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:6580 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7168 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:258 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:613 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:136

Comment: That is not the error the scanner API throws.

Comment: I think that maybe is a proble with the comunication with play-service but I dont know how check it.

Comment: The barscanning API has a set of possible errors. The part of the log copied shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could found someone that had the same problem https://gist.github.com/santansarah/ef744aaf846164ed38826e3a3c68340b#file-uninstall-google-play-services-md

The solucion was reinstall google play service application. In one of my phone this article work for the other  (the older) I had to unistall the upgrade for google play service app too.